# Adding items to a Hashtable LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, hashtable

I have a Hashtable `map` with `LinkedLists` in each element (implementing separate chaining as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining)). How could I go about adding new nodes to each `LinkedList` element in the table?

I'm wracking my brains, and I don't think
`map.get(index).add(new Object);`
would work, simply because the `get()` method of Hashtable gets the Value of a Key, not the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

> map.get(index).add(new Object);

As long as `index` is the key and not a counter and your linked list is stored against this key, that statement would simply work.

Map stores data in (Key, Value) pairs unlike arrays that store in contiguous locations that can be accessed through a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
Map<KeyClass,List<Item>> map = new HashMap<KeyClass,List<Item>>();
```

Try

```
KeyClass key = ...;
List<Item> list = map.get(key);
if (list == null)
{
    list = new LinkedList<Item>();
    map.put(key,list);
}
list.add(...whatever...);
```